# Need count of exact matching string in a text file for a groovy script

Tags: shell, groovy, jenkins-groovy, groovyshell

I am trying to get a count of exact matching string in a file called file.txt for a groovy script.
so suppose my file is :-

```
phone
phone
phone
iphone
phone
iphone
```

Now when i run :-

```
grep -c "phone" file.txt
```

i get the count as 6 and not 4 since iphone also contains the string phone. In shell i can get the exact only string using :-

```
grep -c '\bphone' file.txt
```

But that doesn't work in groovy shell. How to get that working?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in groovy like this:

```
("file.txt" as File).readLines().count{ it=="AA" }
```

Note that this operation is eager and will load the whole file.

If this is a problem, this is a lazy version:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("file.txt")).filter{ it=="AA" }.count()
```

Comment: Thanks cfrick! i used ("file.txt" as File).readLines().count{ it=="healthy" } and it gave me unexpected word. Any idea why?

Comment: I don't know what an "unexpected word" is

Comment: so u mean if i execute ("file.txt" as File).readLines().count{ it=="phone" } it should give me output 4 right?

Comment: You can try this in the groovy shell.  If you see errors or the outcome is wrong, please edit your question and add the new insights.

Comment: ok i am running in jenkins groovy shell [groovy-test] Running shell script
/home/jenkins/workspace/groovy-test@tmp/durable-32d87dd9/script.sh: line 2: syntax error: unexpected word. all i am running is :-   sh 'echo "phone\nphone\niphone\nphone\nphone\niphone" > file.txt' followed by sh '("file.txt" as File).readLines().count{ it=="phone" }'